# Remove elements in std::vector<std::string>

Tags: c++, vector, element

I am trying to use C++ vector instead of C arrays, but I have some problems. This is my code:

```
size_t i;
//Filter save files
for (i = 0; i != files.size(); i++){
    cout << files.at(i).find(FILE_HEAD) << ' ' << files.at(i) << endl;
    if ((files.at(i).find(FILE_HEAD) != 0)){
        files.erase(files.begin() + i);
    }
}
cout << "Found files:\n";
for (i = 0; i != files.size(); i++){
    cout << i << " - " << files.at(i) << endl;
}
```

`files` is a `std::vector<std::string>` and I want to remove all elements which not contain `FILE_HEAD`. But this doesn't work properly, in my test `file.size()` is 14 but it goes in for only 7 times. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Use `std::remove_if`.

Comment: Once you've removed an element, you've decreased the effective size of your vector. This will cause issues with a fixed for loop. For a quick workaround, iterate backwards. Better yet, follow the other suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
files.erase(std::remove_if(files.begin(),files.end(),
            [](const std::string& str){return str.find(FILE_HEAD) == std::string::npos;}),
            file.end());
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know remove_if!

Comment: c++11 warning. it is not supported by some old compilers.

Comment: This is a great answer. I like the use of the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is following: when you erase `i`-th element, you still increase `i`, so you skip one element. Try to add `i--;` right after `files.erase(files.begin() + i);` to fix it (only for testing!). But please do not invent such bicycles! It is better to use std::remove_if instaed of such problematic implementations.

Comment: AFAIK after removing element from vector the iterator is no longer valid. if it is windows code the erase return a valid iterator to allow the loop continue.

Comment: @SHR, but in line `files.at(i).find(FILE_HEAD)` we have getting an access to i-th element, so we skip one element after each `erase()`.